# Laravel eloquent relations won't work as supposed to when searching by id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I currently have 3 tables:

```
Posts:
-id
-text
-user_id
Comments:
-id
-text
-post_id
-user_id
Likes:
-id
-user_id
-comment_id
```

I want to get both Comments and Likes on those comments on my `show()` controller of Posts.
This code in my `Models` seemed to work when using `all()`, however it completely breaks when im trying to search by `id`. It always returns all `Posts`, even though it should only get one.

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comments', 'post_id', 'id');
    }
    public function comment_likes(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            '\App\CommentLikes',
            '\App\Models\Comments',
            'post_id', 'comment_id', 'id'
        );
    }
}
```

And controller code:

```
  public function show($id){
        $query =\App\Models\Posts::find($id)->with('comments')->with('comment_likes')->get();
        if(is_null($query)){
            return response()->json(['Not found'], 404);

        }
        return response()->json($query, 200);
    }
```

Is that even proper way of doing it?

Comment: Define breaks? do you see an error. Right now it is fairly hard to know what needs fixing. Tip: instead of null checking, just use findOrFail() instead on the query.

Comment: There's no error, for whatever reason it just returns all my posts instead of just one. So there's no difference between /posts/1 or /posts/2. Error only pops out when i go to post that doesn't exist

Comment: Ok, apparently it happens even without this hasManyThrough code. Now im confused, it happens when im using any of these relations (comments or comment_likes). Im gonna update the post now

Comment: I have an answer and i do not believe it has anything to do with relations but how you use the query builder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing up query builders and models, the call sequence you have now will execute a new `->get()` query from the model, therefor returning multiple posts.

This happens as `->find()` executes a query, returns 1 element where the id is the parameter. This is now an Eloquent model, therefor you should not call `with()` and `get()` on this. You do that and this will execute a new query, therefor selecting all posts.

If you rearrange the order, it should work as expected.

```
\App\Models\Posts::with('comments')->with('comment_likes')->find($id)
```

Comment: Damn, thank you a lot. Been bashing my head over this for 2 days

Comment: Hope you understand the reason why, as this is very important so you don't make similar mistakes down the line